# Can I create Icons on the fly in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gdi

Since I am not getting anywhere with my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957984/how-to-add-text-to-icon-in-c), I would like to know, are there any ways I can create icons on the fly on WPF?

Comment: What do you mean by 'on the fly'?

Comment: he probably means generating an image using xaml (likely data driven), and saving it as a bitmap

Comment: I mean on demand, Lets say I want to display progress status in Tray icon, rather displaying tool tip, I want to display an icon with display status on top the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, I don't fully understand the details, if you find anything that can be improved, please do comment. Thanks for all the answers and comments.

```
 public static ImageSource GetIconWithText(int digit)
 {
     BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\PomoDomo.ico", 
         UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

     DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

     using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
     {
         // Draw image
         drawingContext.DrawImage(myBitmapImage, new Rect(0, 0, myBitmapImage.Width, 
             myBitmapImage.Height));

         var typeFace = new Typeface(new FontFamily("Verdana"), FontStyles.Normal, 
             FontWeights.ExtraBold, FontStretches.UltraCondensed);
         var formatedText = new FormattedText(digit.ToString(),
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
               typeFace,
               40, 
               System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White);

         //Center the text on Image
         int pointY = (int)(myBitmapImage.Height - formatedText.Height) / 2;
         int pointX = (int)(myBitmapImage.Width - formatedText.Width) / 2;

         drawingContext.DrawText(formatedText, new Point(pointX, pointY));
     }

     RenderTargetBitmap finalBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)myBitmapImage.Width, 
         (int)myBitmapImage.Height, myBitmapImage.DpiX, myBitmapImage.DpiY, 
         PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
     finalBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);
     return finalBitmap;
 }

 private static void SaveImage(RenderTargetBitmap returnBitmap, string pngFileName)
 {
     string fileName = string.Format("{0}.png", pngFileName)
     PngBitmapEncoder image = new PngBitmapEncoder();
     image.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(returnBitmap));
     using (Stream fs = File.Create(fileName))
     {
         image.Save(fs);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need WPF.

Usign GDI+ (`System.Drawing.dll`), you can create a 16x16 `Bitmap`, then call `Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon())`.

Comment: Are you saying I can't do it in WPF?

Comment: No; I'm saying that you _can_ do it in WinForms.

Comment: Why take an additional dependency on System.Drawing and do expensive WPF/GDI interop if you can do it natively in WPF only.

Comment: @bitbonk: In his original question, it sounded like he wanted GDI+.  WPF doesn't have a NotifyIcon, so he needs GDI+ and WinForms anyway.

Comment: @SLaks, I am looking for a solution in WPF.

Comment: Ooops, I didn't see he actually wants a NotityIcon. This will involve win32 interop in any case, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for this.

Comment: @iraSenthil here is a per pixel drawing method http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/WpfPixelDrawing.html

Comment: @Neeraj How do I add text and Image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Taskbar icon progress bar...Sure U have seen, most of the application if doing any scanning or progress things, it displays progress actions on Icon.

Do this in your main form where u included the Icon

```
<Window x:Class="CCTrayHelper.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
    Icon="/CCTrayHelper;component/Images/CCTrayHelperIcon.png">

<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo />
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

Trig it from code behind

```
 private void OnProgress(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (Action)delegate() { TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = TaskbarItemProgressState.None; });
        // Use here your progress type
    }
```

Comment: I need status on tray icon, anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes!! it works only for Windows 7......... @iraSenthil, u means something Like Messenger Icon where if user is busy or not available then it shows some other animation or image over Icon.. right??

Comment: Closer, But I want to add some text instead of some limited icons.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666772/how-can-i-render-text-on-a-writeablebitmap-on-a-background-thread-in-windows-pho) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425950/how-can-i-write-string-on-writeablebitmap) to render text on writeablebitmap